# #1005 - Não pode criar a tabela `db_to_do_list`.`tb_concluido` (erro no. 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, phpmyadmin

Estou postando essa dúvida aqui, pois por mais que tenha pesquisado, não consigo resolve-la

Estou começando a estudar MySQL e o problema que ocorreu foi esse:

```
#1005 - Não pode criar a tabela `db_to_do_list`.`tb_concluido` (erro no. 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

OBS: Já tentei tirar o "DEFAULT 'Vazio'" do fk_conteudo e mesmo assim não funciona.
OBS2: Se eu tirar a última FOREIGN KEY, o código funciona, mas o fk_conteudo que eu precisaria que recuperasse o "conteudo" de tb_lista não funcionaria ;/

As tabelas são essas:

[image: Imagem da tabela tb_lista já criada]

```
CREATE TABLE tb_concluido(
    id_conteudo_concluido INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    fk_id_conteudo INT NOT NULL,
    fk_conteudo TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Vazio',
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_conteudo) REFERENCES tb_lista (id_conteudo),
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_conteudo) REFERENCES tb_lista (conteudo)
)
```

Comment: comigo era uma tabela que estava sem a chave primaria definida errei ao fazer a tabela anterior revisa as tabela que vc ta tentando referenciar veja se elas estão corretas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiramente precisa-se criar a tabela PAI
que no seu caso seria a tabela tb_lista

```
CREATE TABLE tb_lista(
    id_conteudo INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    conteudo TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Posteriormente se cria a tabela filho

```
CREATE TABLE tb_concluido( 
    id_conteudo_concluido INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    fk_id_conteudo INT NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY (fk_id_conteudo) REFERENCES tb_lista (id_conteudo) 
);
```

lembre-se que para cada registro de uma tabela, ela ira mostrar um registro da outra tabela, caso vc precise de uma lista da tabela secundaria, será necessario replicar os dados da tabela principal
Um exemplo seria um pai pode ter mais de um filho, mas um filho só terá um pai, ou seja, se vc tiver irmão o nome do pai será replicado.
Outro problema que esta em seu codigo é a Normalização, ela diz que se faz referencia entre as tabelas atraves de um ID, evitando-se fazer por VARCHAR.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta ! Eu não conhecia sobre isso que o senhor mencionou sobre "normalização". Pesquisei aqui e parece que as chaves estrangeiras são sempre feitas por IDs mesmo, eu não sabia disso rsrs. Me salvou rsrs Muito obrigado mesmo, de coração huasha Estava empacado aqui nisso e o senhor me ajudou muito agora !! ^^ haha. Um dia espero ajudar de volta ^^